# How to change every black pixel to a special color?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, color

I want to extract all video frames as images and change every black (pure black) pixel of the images to a special color. (R=3,G=3,B=3)

I used this command to extract video frames :

```
ffmpeg -I myVideo.avi -f image2 -vf yadif -vcodec png image%d
```

Please tell me how to change every black pixel of the images to color that I want? (I want R=3,G=3,B=3)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LUT or GEQ filters for this.

e.g. with LUT

```
ffmpeg -i myVideo.avi
       -vf
       "yadif,format=rgb24,
        lutrgb=r='if(eq(val,0),3,val)':g='if(eq(val,0),3,val)':b='if(eq(val,0),3,val)'"
image%d.png
```

Comment: That code looks like it doesn't do as asked. For example a pixel with 0, 100, 0 is changed to 3, 100, 3